# SciPy: converting 1/0 sparse matrix to 0/1 sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

What is the fastest way to convert 1/0 sparse matrix to 0/1 sparse matrix without using `todense()` method?

Example:

Source matrix looks like:

```
matrix([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Result matrix is:

```
matrix([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

The source matrix is too large, so I can use only sparse representation of matrixes.

Comment: Why don't you want to use dense? One of your matrices will be at least 50% dense, this will take up a lot of memory if matrix is represented as sparse. You will probably save memory by making your matrices dense, especially if they are `np.int8` type.

Comment: @Akavall here is just example, the real matrix is much more sparse

Comment: @TuralGurbanov: but if the real matrix is very sparse, the output will be very dense after you flip 0 to 1 and 1 to 0, no?

Comment: @DSM yes, you're right... But, nevertheless, I think that sparse representation will take less memory than dense one.

Comment: It takes less memory if a matrix is, well, sparse.  If it's dense, then you have to record both the value and some kind of indexing information (which varies depending on the storage structure).  For example, a 100x100 matrix of doubles takes much less memory as a raw chunk than the dictionary `{(0,0): 1.1, (0, 1): 2.1, ...}`.  That's the tradeoff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DSM is correct. There are many representations of sparse matrices, but if you use dictionary format, then you need 3 numbers to represent one element (row, col, value). Thus you need `3*np` memory (`np` is the number of nonzeros). If use a dense format, then you need `n*m` memory. Therefore, sparse representation is useful only when `np/(n*m) < 3` for this case, which means the sparsity is less than `1/3`.

On the other hand, if you flip your `1`s and `0`s, then the sparsity will be one minus the original one. Thus, if the original matrix is sparse, then there is no way that your flipped matrix is sparse.

If you only need `1`s and `0`s in your matrix then I would recommend writing your own representation of the compressed sparse matrix. For example, you can read your matrix from top-left, row-wise, and if there are any consecutive `1`s or `0`s, then you can do something like `1 3 0 2 1 0 1 4`, which means "three consecutive `1`s, two consecutive `0`s, `1`, `0`, four consecutive `1`s". Depending on your use of your matrix, my suggestion may be useless, but it is worth thinking about it.

Comment: `3*np` is a good rough approximation; however, it is not always accurate, since row, col and value are of different data types: row and col are `np.int32` by default, while there is probably a way to change that, we can see a scenario where we can't if row or col needs to be greater than 32767. Therefore when working with `np.int8` data the matrix has to be more sparse, since indices take up disproportional amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to spam, but on the second thought, if the matrix only has 1s and 0s, then you can use one int32 number to represent 32 elements (matrix needs to be dense). Then flipping 1s and 0s is just a bit manipulation and shouldn't be hard. This will make the size of matrix to 1/32 and also the operation should be roughly 32 times faster.

Comment: You can add this as an edit to the original post, theres no need to post a new answer for it.

Comment: well I'm not sure if he will read it if I just edit my original post because he won't get a notification.